A formula resembling the integral mean value on Kähler manifolds
I am reading comparison geometry of holomorphic bisectional curvature for Kähler manifolds and limit spaces by John Lott. I have a problem when reading the proof of the following theorem:

Theorem. Let $M$ be a complete Kähler manifold. Given $ K \in \mathbb{R} $, the manifold $ M $ has $ B K \geq K $ if and only if it satisfies the following property. Let $ i: \overline{D^{2}} \rightarrow M $ be an embedding of a disk into $ M $ that is holomorphic on $ D^{2} $. Let $ \Sigma $ be the image of $ i $. Let $ d A $ denote the area form on $ \Sigma $. Let $ z $ be the local coordinate on $ D^{2} $, and let $ \theta \in[0,2 \pi) $ be the local coordinate on $ \partial \overline{D^{2}} $. Then
$$d_{K, p}^{2}(0) \geq \frac{2}{\pi} \iint_{\Sigma} \log |z| d A+\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\partial \Sigma} d_{K, p}^{2}(\theta) d \theta,$$
where the "$0$" on the left-hand side denotes $i(0)$, the center of $\Sigma$, and
$$d_{K,p}^{2}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} -\frac{4}{K} \log \cos \left(d_p \sqrt{\frac{K}{2}}\right) & \text { if } K>0, \\
d_p^{2} & \text { if } K=0, \\
\frac{4}{-K} \log \cosh \left(d_p \sqrt{\frac{-K}{2}}\right) & \text { if } K<0,
\end{array}\right.$$
$d_p$ is the distance from $p$.
Partial proof. "$\Longrightarrow$" Suppose that $ B K \geq K $. From Proposition 3.6, or more precisely its proof, we know that $ \sqrt{-1} \partial \bar{\partial} d_{K, p}^{2} / 2 \leq \omega_{\Sigma} $ as currents on $\Sigma$. The solution to $\sqrt{-1} \partial \bar{\partial} f / 2=\omega_{\Sigma} $ on $ \Sigma $, with $f|_{\partial \Sigma}=\left.d_{K, p}^{2}\right|_{\partial \Sigma} $ has
$$\boxed{f(0) = \frac{2}{\pi} \iint_{\Sigma} \log |z| d A+\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\partial \Sigma} d_{K, p}^{2}(\theta) d \theta}.$$
As $f-d_{K,p}^2$ is subharmonic on $\Sigma$, and vanishes on $\partial\Sigma$, the desired inequality follows.
"$\Longleftarrow$" $\cdots\cdots$
Proposition 3.6
Let $ M $ be a complete Kähler manifold. If $ B K \geq K $, then for all $ p \in M $,
$$\sqrt{-1} \partial \bar{\partial} d_{K, p}^{2} / 2 \leq \omega$$
as currents on $ M $.

Question: I have no idea how $f(0)$ was suddenly expressed by such a large formula, but this formula looks more like integral mean value. Can someone tell me how this formula was derived scrupulously, or which theorem guarantees this formula? Any help would be appreciated!
Edit: The confused formula has corresponding analogues in Riemannian case, as shown below:

Let $(M, g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold. We consider lower sectional curvature bounds; for simplicity, assume that $(M, g)$ has nonnegative sectional curvature. Given $p\in M$, then
$$\operatorname{Hess}\left(d_{p}^{2} / 2\right) \leq g \quad \text{(this is an analogue of proposition 3.6)}$$
away from the cut locus $C_{p}$ of $p$.
Let $\{\gamma(t)\}_{t \in[0, L]}$ be a unit-speed geodesic in $M-C_{p}$. Write $d_{p}(t)$ for $d_{p}(\gamma(t))$. It follows from the above formula that $\frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}\left(d_{p}^{2}(t) / 2\right) \leq 1$, that is, $\frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}\left(d_{p}^{2}(t) / 2-\right.   \left.t^{2} / 2\right) \leq 0$. In other words, $d_{p}^{2}(t)-t^{2}$ is concave on $[0, L]$. Then
$$d_{p}^{2}(t)-t^{2} \geq \frac{t}{L}\left(d_{p}^{2}(L)-L^{2}\right)+\left(1-\frac{t}{L}\right) d_{p}^{2}(0)$$
or
$$d_{p}^{2}(t) \geq \frac{t}{L} d_{p}^{2}(L)+\left(1-\frac{t}{L}\right) d_{p}^{2}(0)-t(L-t) .$$
Substituting $t=\frac L2$ into the formula above, we can find that $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\partial \Sigma} d_{K, p}^{2}(\theta) d \theta$ is an analogue of $\frac12(d_p^2(L)+d_p^2(0))$, and $\frac{2}{\pi} \iint_{\Sigma} \log |z| d A$ is an analogue of $-\frac{L^2}4$.


It is called a Poisson-Jensen formula. For example, see Proposition 1.25 from the textbook "Degenerate complex Monge-Ampere equations". Note that here we are using Laplacian induced by 1-dim complex structure, independent of the metric.

@KiyoonEum Yes, but I found that subsequently, the author states "If $\Sigma$ is an embedded holomorphic disk in $M$, then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\quad d_{K,p}^2(0)-\frac2\pi\iint_\Sigma\log|z|dA-\frac1{2\pi}\int_{\partial\Sigma}d_{K,p}^2(\theta)d\theta\&=\frac2\pi\iint_\Sigma\log|z|\left(\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar\partial d_{K,p}^2/2-\omega_\Sigma\right)."
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}But $d_{K,p}^2$ doesn't seem to be $C^1$ and subharmonic.

Here, we need to use the fact that the Laplacian of Kähler potential on a complex-$1$-dimensional Kähler manifold $M$ must be $2$, as shown below:
Denote by $\omega$ the foundational $2$-form on $M$. Since $M$ is complex-$1$-dimensional, $\omega$ can be written as
$$\omega=ifdz\wedge d\bar z$$
for some real function $f$. Let $\phi$ be the Kähler potential, that is $\omega=i\partial\bar\partial\phi$, then
$$ifdz\wedge d\bar z=\omega=i\partial\bar\partial\phi=i\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z\partial\bar z}dz\wedge d\bar z,$$
so
$$\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z\partial\bar z}=f.$$
Recall that the Laplacian on a Kähler manifold is defined as
$$\Delta f=2 g^{\alpha \bar{\beta}} \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial z^{\alpha} \partial \bar{z}^{\beta}} .$$
Therefore,
$$\Delta\phi=2\frac1f\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z\partial\bar z}=2.$$
Another fact we need to use is the Green's representation formula. Green's representation formula derivation:
Let $\Omega$ be a domain, $u$, $v\in C^2(\bar\Omega)$. We have Green's second identity
$$\int_\Omega(v\Delta u-u\Delta v)dx=\int_{\partial\Omega}\left(v\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec n}-u\frac{\partial v}{\partial \vec n}\right)ds.$$
The $2$-dimensional fundamental solution of the Laplace equation is
$$\Gamma(x):=\frac1{2\pi}\log|x-x_0|.$$
But its singularity at $x=x_0$ will prevent us from replace $v$ by $\Gamma$. Then for sufficiently small $\rho$, we replace $\Omega$ by $\Omega-\bar B(x_0,\rho)$. So we have
$$\int_{\Omega-B(x_0,\rho)}\Gamma\Delta u~dx=\int_{\partial\Omega}\left(\Gamma\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec n}-u\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial \vec n}\right)ds+\int_{\partial B(x_0,\rho)}\left(\Gamma\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec n}-u\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial \vec n}\right)ds.$$
Note that
$$\int_{\partial B(x_0,\rho)}\Gamma\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec n}ds=\Gamma(\rho)\int_{\partial B(x_0,\rho)}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec n}ds\leq n\omega_n\rho^{n-1}\Gamma(\rho)\sup_{B(x_0,\rho)}|{\rm grad}~u|\rightarrow0,\quad \text{as}~\rho\rightarrow0,$$
and
$$\int_{\partial B(x_0,\rho)}u\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial \vec n}ds=-\Gamma'(\rho)\int_{\partial B(x_0,\rho)}u~ds=\frac{-1}{|\partial B(x_0,\rho)|}\int_{\partial B(x_0,\rho)}u~ds\rightarrow-u(x_0),\quad \text{as}~\rho\rightarrow0.$$
Therefore we have the Green's representation formula:
$$u(x_0)=\int_\Omega\Gamma\Delta u~dx+\int_{\partial\Omega}\left(u\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial \vec n}-\Gamma\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec n}\right)ds.$$
Finally, we have
\begin{align*}
f(0)&=\iint_{D^2}\frac1{2\pi}\log|z|\cdot\Delta_\Sigma f~ dA+\int_{\partial D^2}\left(f\cdot\frac1{2\pi|z|}-\frac1{2\pi}\log|z|\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec n}\right)ds\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi} \iint_{D^2} \log |z| d A+\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2\pi} d_{K, p}^{2}(\theta) d \theta.
\end{align*}
(Note $\Delta_\Sigma f=4.$)
